# Unable to Launch Qt uic

Tags: python-3.x, qt4, pyside

I have installed Qt designer 4.8.2, Pyside, and Python 3.3.   When I create a form with Qt designer I am not able to see the code when clicking on view code.  The error message is:"Unable to launch C:\Qt\4.8.2\bin\uic".
I have the pyuic under C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic.  Please help.

Comment: It looks like that path is hard-wired into Qt Designer. I usually just setup a Makefile that calls `uic`, so you don't need to use Designer to view your generated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can certainly use Qt Designer for creating UIs for PySide/PyQt, you should be aware that it is primarily a C++ tool - it doesn't have any built in support for Python. So the "View Code..." command you refer to only produces C++ code - which is probably not much use to you if you intend using PySide or PyQt.

Qt Designer UI files are in an XML format (they usually have a .ui extension).

To use them with Python, there are basically two options:

1. Load the .ui files directly into your application.
2. Convert the .ui files into Python modules using an external tool.

There are several differences between PySide and PyQt in how these two options are implemented.

For PyQt, the full documention for both options can be found [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/designer.html).

For PySide, the documentation for option 1 can be found [here](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtUiTools/QUiLoader.html#detailed-description) - but it does not look like there is any documentation for option 2. However, the external tool for PySide (which is called `pyside-uic`) works very similarly to the one for PyQt (which is called called `pyuic4`).

If you need more general information about how to get started using Qt with Python, try the [PySide Wiki](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aLanguageBindings%3a%3aPySide) or the [PyQt Wiki](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/StartPage?action=show&redirect=FrontPage).

Comment: +1 for focusing on the distinction of Qt Designer being targeted for C++ projects. I used it solely for doing complicated layouts, or just visual brainstorming. Most of the features should be disregarded when doing a PyQt/PySide project. Just use it to do a layout and save a ui and/or resource file.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to generate the py file from the ui file.  However, when I run the generated python code I have the following errors.  I seem to have a problem with the docstring?? Thanks much.    
text, filename = doctest._load_testfile(filename, None, False, "utf-8")File "C:\Python33\lib\doctest.py", line 223, in _load_testfile
return f.read(), filename File "C:\Python33\lib\codecs.py", line 300, in decode(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte

Answer (score 6):

Just create a directory where it search for uic.exe file  and copy existing  uic.exe file to that directory.

My example :
When I clicked View Code it shows Error asking for file uic.exe in path
C:\python374\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\Qt\bin\bin

But I found uicexe file is in C:\python374\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\Qt\bin folder
So I created another bin folder and copied uic.exe into that folder . That solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you were looking to generate python code, you would do this from the console. So, if you saved your file from the program as 'untitled', the default, run this:

```
 pyuic5 -m untitled.ui -o untitled.py
```

Making sure your working directory is the file location of 'untitled.ui'. It will then spit untitled.py into the same place.

Answer (score 4):

Create a folder called bin inside the folder and move the exe inside uic.exe. It shows the code when click the view code from the QT designer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make

> *Form* -> *View code*

work, directly from *Qt Designer* using either Qt4 or Qt5, you can just create a symbolic link from where *Qt Designer* is looking, pointing to where your *pyuic5.exe* executable is. With your example, it would be:

```
mklink /H "C:\Qt\4.8.2\bin\uic.exe" "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyuic4.exe"
```

Which is:

```
mklink /H "Path\to\uic.exe\file\Qt\designer\is\looking\for" "Path\to\actual\location\of\pyuic4.exe\or\pyuic5.exe\file"
```

Make sure the folder where "C:\Qt\4.8.2\bin\uic.exe" will reside exists obviously.

Answer (score 0):

#### For Linux computers

If anyone still stuck with this problem and you are using Linux.

You can find the required `uic` file in `venv-path/python3.x/site-packages/PySide2/uic`
Copy this file, and create a new folder `bin` inside the Qt folder.`venv-path/python3.x/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/bin`

now place the `uic` file there, such that, the final `uic` path is:
`venv-path/python3.x/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/bin/uic`

**Note:**:

- *venv-path* is the path to you python virtual-environment.
- *3.x* is the appropriate version of the Python in the virtual-environment. (In my case it's 3.8)

#### Final Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
python -c "import os; import PySide6; src = PySide6.__path__[0]; dst = src + '/bin'; os.mkdir(dst) if not os.path.exists(dst) else None; os.symlink(src + '/uic.exe', dst + '/uic.exe')"
```

**I had the same [error\warning message on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLU5c.png) with `pyside6-designer`**, I just run the above line as administrator and everything now works as expected *(The line, simply creates a link of the `uic.exe` inside a `bin`-folder under the `Pyside6` module's folder)*.